# nvim: `vim.o.cmdheight=0` looses the 'recording @a' macro messages

Tags: neovim, statusline

When I set  `vim.o.cmdheight=0` in neovim, then use macros. The `recording @a` messages are lost.

Aside for reverting back to `vim.o.cmdheight=1`, how can I display these messages in [lualine](https://github.com/nvim-lualine/lualine.nvim)?

[image: vim.o.cmdheight=1 with a recording ongoing]

Environment:

```
NVIM v0.8.2
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by runneradmin@fv-az28-353
+ lualine
```

Comment: set cmdheight=1  back again?

Comment: Here is a potential solution from reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/xy0tu1/comment/irfegvd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). If the solution work for you feel free to answer your own question with detail about how you implemented it. It could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two simple autocmd if you're using lua configs

```
vim.cmd [[ autocmd RecordingEnter * set cmdheight=1 ]]
vim.cmd [[ autocmd RecordingLeave * set cmdheight=0 ]]
```

This will automatically enable cmdheight=1 when starting recording and when you stop it will take you back to the cmdheight=0. This is the workaround I'm using on my setup until they fix this bug. Tested on NVIM v0.9.0.

Comment: Here's the Issue on github: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/19193